# Getting the Azure AD App role name from a Group AppRole Assignment Using Azure Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I have Azure AD App role assignments to groups in an environment that I can only access using Powershell. To get the AD APP roles assigned to a particular AD Group, I used the command `Get-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId XXXX-XXX...` where the objectId here is the group object id, which works, but the problem is that the output of the command shows only the objectId of the App role, and that objectId isn't for some reason a valid GUID, which makes me unable to use it to query the name of the app role.

Please see below snapshot

[image]

Comment: Just use `Get-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId XXXX-XXX | fl`, you can get more properties in the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To query the name of the app role, you could use the command below.

```
$rs = Get-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId <object-id>
foreach($r in $rs){
    $app = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $r.ResourceId
    $DisplayName = ($app.AppRoles | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq $r.Id}).DisplayName
    Write-Host $DisplayName of $app.AppDisplayName
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, you need to filter your app role with the display name in `Get-AzureADGroup` and pass it to `Get-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment`

```
$GroupId = (Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq 'displayname'" -top 1).objectid

Get-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $GroupId
```